# Edit duplicate layer only in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing

In QGIS I want to duplicate a layer and then delete some polygons from the duplicate only, without deleting them from the original layer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, because duplicate layers *share the same data source*.

I recommend to 'save layer as...' with option 'add saved layer to project' checked. This copy you may edit without changing the source layer.

**QGIS 3:**

In QGIS 3 it's right-click the layer then 'Export... | Save Features As...':

[image]

The option 'Add saved file to map' remains the same:

[image]